# Image file not found in Texmaker

Tags: graphics, miktex, texmaker

In texmaker I cannot inlude an image, when compiling quickbuild PDF I get the error:

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./coretip.jpg): reading JPEG image failed (no JPEG header found)

Before including the image, the quickbuild was working (by closing and opening texmaker for compiling). The code I'm running is saved in the same directory as the image file.

My code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\graphicspath{{"C:\Users\IWQ\Documents\test"}}
\begin{document}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{{coretip.jpg}}
\end{document}
```

What I have tried:

```
\includegraphics[scale=1]{{"coretip.jpg"}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{{.\coretip.jpg}}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{"coretip.jpg"}
\includegraphics[scale=1]{{coretip}}
```

And the combinations of these variations,

```
\graphicspath{{C:\Users\IWQ\Documents\test}}
\graphicspath{"C:\Users\IWQ\Documents\test"}
```

And the combinations of these variations. Have also tried to leave \graphicspath out.

I have tried to put the file directory in the root of MikTex, and I have tried to put the file directory in the PdfLaTex of the configure texmaker window.

pdflatex -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

pdflatex "C:\Users\IWQ\Documents\test" -synctex=1 -interaction=nonstopmode %.tex

Nothing I have tried works, and I have not found any other answers which cover other methods. I am used to working with overleaf, however online working is not allowed at my current company. Please help me I am wasting hours to get texmaker to work and it's really counterintuitive.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look the error message is not "I didn't found the image". The error says "reading JPEG image failed (no JPEG header found)". And this means that the image is broken. Try to resave it.

Comment: also don't you get undefined command errors from `\graphicspath{{"C:\Users\IWQ\Documents\test"}}`  you should use `/` not ``\ `

Comment: `pdflatex "C:\Users\IWQ\Documents\test" ` indicates that the file (not teh folder) ids called test in which case the graphics path should not have `test` at teh end, but it is much better not to use graphics path and use `pdflatex test` after changeing folder to `\users\IWQ\Documents`   all paths in the file are relative to where you run pdflatex not relative to the document

Comment: If I try another test image, I get the following error:

LaTeX Warning: File `{"test.jpeg"}' not found on input line 77.
! Package pdftex.def Error: File `test.jpeg' not found: using draft setting.

Same error when I change the "\" into "/" in the \graphicspath.

Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Don't overdo with braces and quotes. If the image is available and you use the right name, `\includegraphics{test}` or `\includegraphics{test.jpeg}` should work.

Comment: you are just showing fragments that are not consistent and haven't really given enough information. what is you image called is it `test.jpg` or `test.jpeg`  where is it, is it in `C:\Users\IWQ\Documents` or in `C:\Users\IWQ\Documents\test` ?  If the graphics path is used at all then `\graphicspath{{"C:\Users\IWQ\Documents` will generate errors that `\Users` , `\IWQ` and `\Documents` are undefined commands.

Comment: I have a directory called Documents\test. In this directory, I have a test.tex which I am trying to compile. My image is called coretip.jpg, however as someone mentioned my image may be broken, I made a new image called test.jpeg. 

If I omit the \graphicspath and I use \includegraphics{test}, I get the error:

!pdfTeX error: pdflatex (file ./test.pdf): xpdf: reading PDF image failed

When I close and open texmaker after this (which is the usual method for recompiling) I get an error message: File not found.

If I remove the \includegraphics line, the compiling works again.

Comment: yes that is expected you should cd to documents\test then do pdflatex test  so that pdftex can see the image in the same folder